# Edits in ArcGIS Survey123 Connect are missing

Tags: editing, arcgis-survey123

I created a Survey and published then I made some edits in ArcGIS Survey 123 connect. When I published the Survey my original edits made in Design mode are gone.

I have lost my entire Survey. I am not getting a notification saying that I cannot make edit in Design mode because the Survey was done in ArcGIS Survey 123 connect.

How can I find my original survey?